# D3 plus wrapping text in circles

Tags: javascript, d3.js, d3plus

So I've been trying to use D3plus in order to wrap text inside circles but with no success. In my application I have a few circle/text pairs, put together into a "g" element. In my code, after I create the "g" elements and append circles and text to it I call the d3plus `d3plus.textwrap()`function like this:

```
d3plus.textwrap()
  //selecting the first text element
  .container(d3.select("#Text0"))
  .draw();
```

However, instead of getting wrapped, the text simply disappears. The text is still visible as an element in DOM, but for some reason its size becomes 0x0. Does anyone know what is wrong here?

Comment: try this code `d3plus.textwrap().container(d3.select("#Text0")).resize(true)
  .draw();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use method `resize as true` as following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="//d3plus.org/js/d3.js"></script>
<script src="//d3plus.org/js/d3plus.js"></script>
<style>
  svg {font-family:"Helvetica","Arial",sans-serif;height: 425px;margin: 25px; width: 400px;}
  .type {fill: #888;text-anchor: middle;}
  .shape {fill: #eee;stroke: #ccc;}
</style>
<svg>
  <circle class="shape" r="85px" cx="275px" cy="300px"></circle>
  <text id="circleResize" class="wrap" y="260px" x="200px" font-size="12">
Appeared Text inside circle </text> 
</svg>
<script>  
  d3plus.textwrap()
.container(d3.select("#circleResize"))
.resize(true)
.draw();
</script>
```